# Histogram matching of 3D datasets using L2 norm minimisation (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, least-squares

I need to perform some elementary histogram matching on 2 sets of 3D data. This is part of a larger algorithm.

My goal is to perform this by minimising the following cost function:

|| cumpdf(f(A)) - cumpdf(B) || .^2

where:

cumpdf is the cumulative histogram

f() is linear transformation a*A + b where a/b are affine coefficients to be
               determined

A is the image to be transformed and B is the image to be matched

I am using lsqcurvefit however I have run into some trouble and therefore really need some help.

```
A(maskA==0)=0;
B(maskB==0)=0;

[na,~] = hist(A(maskA~=0),500);
na = na ./ numel(A(maskA~=0));
x_data = cumsum(na);

[nb,~] = hist(B(maskB~=0),500);
nb = nb ./ numel(B(maskB~=0));
y_data = cumsum(nb);

xo = [1.5 -200];
[coeff,~] = lsqcurvefit(@cost,xo,x_data,y_data);

function F = cost(x,xc)
F = x(1).*A + x(2);
[nc,~] = hist(C(maskA~=0),500);
nc = nc / numel(C(maskA~=0));
xc = cumsum(nc);
```

Amask and Bmask just represent some indexing I need to do.

My question is: I know that the above is wrong. However, I think it represents best what I want to do, regarding the cost function and the goal. Some help would me much appreciated!

Comment: You should explain better what does "some trouble" means. What is your specific problem?

Comment: I have tried performing the minimisation on the histogram counts, hoping this would match the histograms to a certain extent, by doing the following:

x_data and y_data = counts and
function F = cost(x,x_data) --> F = x(1).*A + x(2)

Doing so gives me the same answer as if I solve the equation [a b] = [x_data 1] \ y_data. However, this doesn't match the histograms terribly well and I don't think its minimising the defined cost function.

This has prompted me to try and write the cost function as defined in the question. However, MATLAB will not accept it and I cannot fathom how to make it work